# No Persistence provider for EntityManager named XXX Spring-jpa-hibernate-mysql-Maven project

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

Hi I have started to use Spring and JPA for the first time, I've tried many tutorials and questions here at stack overflow.But no success so I hope some one can give me a clear way out of this problem. I'm developing a toy application to get confident with the technology before I start the real project, I'm using Java, Spring, Hibernate, JPA and MySQL on a Maven-non web module project using java annotations as much as possible and as little xml as possible, I've found many web base application full of xml files but was unable to understand how to correct my project. The only thing I am able to understand is that I need to declare a persistence unit somehow telling the entity manager what to do, but there is no META-INF folder in my project (should create one?) AND most persistance.xml files I've found declare little more than what I have in my jpa-handler-conf.xml which seems to otherwise work fine.
So here are the project components:

The Beans:

```
package hp.esercizi.beans;
imports omitted...

@Component
@Entity
@Table(name = "AUTORE")
public class Autore {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "NOME", length = 20)
    private String nome;
    @Column(name = "COGNOME", length = 20)
    private String cognome;
    @OneToMany(targetEntity=Autore.class, mappedBy="amici")
    private List<Autore> amici;


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public List<Autore> getAmici() {
        return amici;
    }
    public void setAmici(List<Autore> amici) {
        this.amici = amici;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public String getCognome() {
        return cognome;
    }
    public void setCognome(String cognome) {
        this.cognome = cognome;
    }
}
```

---

```
package hp.esercizi.beans;
imports omitted... 

@Component
@Entity
@Table(name = "MESSAGGIO")
public class Messaggio {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "TESTO", nullable = false, length = 200)
    private String testo;
    @ManyToOne 
    @JoinColumn(name="AUTORE_ID")
    private Autore autore;


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getTesto() {
        return testo;
    }
    public void setTesto(String testo) {
        this.testo = testo;
    }
    public Autore getAutore() {
        return autore;
    }
    public void setAutore(Autore autore) {
        this.autore = autore;
    }
}
```

The DAOs:

```
package hp.esercizi.dao;
imports omitted...

public interface AutoreDAO {

    public EntityManager getEntityManager();

    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager);

    public void insert(Autore autore);

    public List<Autore> selectAll();

    public Autore findAutoreByID(Long id);
}
```

---

```
package hp.esercizi.dao;
imports omitted... 

@Repository("AutoreDAO")
@Transactional
public class AutoreDAOJPA2Impl implements AutoreDAO {

    private static final String SELECT_QUERY = "select a from autore a";

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {

        return entityManager;
    }

    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {

        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    public void insert(Autore autore) {

        entityManager.persist(autore);
    }

    public List<Autore> selectAll() {

        Query query = (Query) entityManager.createQuery(SELECT_QUERY);
        List<Autore> autori = (List<Autore>)  query.getResultList();
        return autori;
    }

    public Autore findAutoreByID(Long id) {

         return entityManager.find(Autore.class, id);
    }
}
```

---

```
package hp.esercizi.dao;
imports omitted... 

public interface MessaggioDAO {

    public EntityManager getEntityManager();

    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager);

    public void insert(Messaggio messaggio);

    public List<Messaggio> selectAll();
```

### }

```
package hp.esercizi.dao;
imports omitted...

@Repository("MessaggioDAO")
@Transactional
public class MessaggioDAOJPA2Impl implements MessaggioDAO {

    private static final String SELECT_QUERY = "select m from messaggio m";

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {

        return entityManager;
    }

    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {

        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    public void insert(Messaggio messaggio) {

        entityManager.persist(messaggio);
    }

    public List<Messaggio> selectAll() {

        Query query = (Query) entityManager.createQuery(SELECT_QUERY);
        List<Messaggio> messaggi = (List<Messaggio>)  query.getResultList();
        return messaggi;
    }
}
```

Entity Manager and Data Source configuration XML (jpa-handler-conf.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.8.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd">

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="vendorAdaptor" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="hp.esercizi" />
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="abstractVendorAdaptor" abstract="true">
        <!-- <property name="generateDdl" value="${db.generate}" /> -->
        <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
        <property name="showSql" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="vendorAdaptor"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
        parent="abstractVendorAdaptor">
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB_SpringContext" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="Lavoro01" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <constructor-arg ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />

</beans>
```

The context configuration:

```
package hp.esercizi.utility;
imports omitted...

@ComponentScan("hp.esercizi.beans")
public class BeansConfig {
}


package hp.esercizi.utility;
imports omitted...

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("hp.esercizi.dao")
public class DataSourceConfig {

}


package hp.esercizi.utility;
imports omitted...

@Configuration
@Import({BeansConfig.class , DataSourceConfig.class})
@ImportResource("jpa-handler-conf.xml")
public class SpringConfig {
}
```

The Main:

```
package hp.esercizi.main;
imports omitted... 

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringConfig.class);
        EntityManagerFactory emfactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("AutoreDAO");
        EntityManager entitymanager = emfactory.createEntityManager( );
        entitymanager.getTransaction( ).begin( );

        Messaggio msg = (Messaggio) context.getBean("messaggio");
        entitymanager.merge(msg);
        Autore aut = (Autore) context.getBean("autore");
        entitymanager.merge(aut);

        msg.setTesto("Ciao Mondo!!!");
        aut.setNome("Mario");
        aut.setCognome("Rossi");
        System.out.println(msg.getTesto());
        System.out.println(msg.getAutore().getNome() + " " + msg.getAutore().getCognome());

        entitymanager.persist(msg);
        entitymanager.getTransaction().commit();

        Messaggio msg2 = entitymanager.find(Messaggio.class, 1);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {

            System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(msg2));

        } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        entitymanager.close( );
        emfactory.close( );
    }
}
```

The pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>esercizi</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringContext</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.CR2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.CR2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: I've somehow solved it by adding a "presistence.xml" duplicating values form "datasource" bean in "jpa-handler-conf.xml", it still looks strange to me I've to write twice the same thing, could anyone clarify?

Comment: It is strange, but it is necessary; Hibernate is not integratable for 100% in spring-jpa.